# 301 редирект не хочет работает со знаком вопроса в GET

Tags: .htaccess, get, http-status-code-301

Есть ссылка вида

> site.ru/1/

Есть редирект, который должен перенаправлять на

> site2.ru/test?start=1111|

Плюс к этому должен прибавится GET запрос вида

> ?clid=222

Но я так понимаю с 2 вопросительными знаками это не работает, каким образом можно исключить первый  символ из запроса? что бы на выходе было [https://site2.ru/test?start=1111|clid=222](https://site2.ru/test?start=1111%7Cclid=222)

Код редиректа самый простой

```
Redirect 301 /1/ https://site2.ru/test?start=1111|
```

Comment: символ `?` отделяет _путь_ в адресе от _параметров_. Сами параметры сцепляются через `&`, так что в вашем случае будет ?start=...&clid=...`